# Foolproof RequiredIf condition with false status not working

Tags: c#, validation, foolproof-validation

I have a `JoinStatus` field with `True or False` condition. I also have 2 textboxes named `JoiningDate` and `NotJoiningReason`.If user selects checkbox(`True Condition`) `JoiningDate textbox` should be validated else (`False Condition`)`NotJoiningReason textbox` should be validated.

I am trying to achieve this using Foolproof,but the problem is `False Condition` is not getting validated.

**ViewModel**

```
public bool JoinStatus { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("JoinStatus",true,ErrorMessage="foooooooooooooooo")]
    public DateTime? JoinDate { get; set; }

[RequiredIf("JoinStatus",false, ErrorMessage = "foooooooooooooooo111111111111")]
    public string NotJoiningReason { get; set; }
```

**HTML**

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.JoinStatus, new { @class = "chkbxSwitchReverse", @id = "chkbxJoinStatus", })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JoinDate,
               new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Specify Month ", @id = "txtJoinDate",@readonly=true, @style = "background-color:white" })

  @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.NotJoiningReason
                    new { @class = "form-control ", @id = "txtNotJoiningReason", @placeholder = "Not joining reason" })
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="~/plugins/foolproofValidation/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/foolproofValidation/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/plugins/foolproofValidation/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have tested this (without the htmlAttributes) and it works fine for me. Not sure why you would have `@readonly = true` (it should be `@readonly = "readonly"`) which would make the textarea not editable and therefore could not be changed if there was a validation error.

Comment: `Readonly` condition is not for `textarea` also now i noticed that I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined` on `MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js`.But all condition except the above mentioned scenario is working properly.

Comment: See if you are getting a 404 in fiddler or dev toolbar when you load the page. Could there be a js file missing?

Comment: @shahkalpesh there is no such error like that.I am getting error in one of the lines of `MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js`.Above I have showed how the script is being referenced.