# Loading Remote Data in Select2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-select2

I am using `Select2's Loading Remote Data Functionality`.The problem is that data is not getting loaded on the `dropdownlist`.On keypress `remote function` is getting called and data is returning properly,but its not showing in dropdownlist.

**HTML**

```
<div class=" form-group col-md-4" data-url="@Url.Action("GetStudentWalkInnName")" id="WalkinnName">
 <div>
    <label for="txtEmployee" class=" control-label">
                      Name
    </label>                               
 </div>
  <div>
        <select class="form-control " id="ddlName"></select>
  </div>                    
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
//REGISTRATION=>INDEX.JS
$(function () {

var ddlNameUrl=$("#WalkinnName").data("url");
$("#ddlName").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for Name",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
        url: ddlNameUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                term: params.term, // search term
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {

            params.page = params.page || 1;

            return {
                results: data,

            };
        }

    }
});

});
```

**Controller is**

```
 public JsonResult GetStudentWalkInnName(string term)
    {
        try
        {
            var walkInnNameList = _db.StudentWalkInns
                                .Where(s => s.CandidateName.StartsWith(term))
                                .Select(x => new
                                {
                                    Id=x.Id,
                                    Text=x.CandidateName
                                }).ToList();
            return Json(walkInnNameList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the examples in the docs, it appears that it needs to be lower case names - try with `.Select(x => new { id = x.Id, text = x.CandidateName });`

Comment: Silly mistake.Could not find proper documentation regarding the above mentioned scenario.Please post the answer along with the link of documentation examples:)

Comment: If possible kindly look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217828/passing-selected-value-to-jquerys-select2-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array), the format if the data should be an array of objects with names `id` and `name` i.e. lowercase (not `Id` and `Name`).

Change you query to

```
var walkInnNameList = _db.StudentWalkInns
    .Where(s => s.CandidateName.StartsWith(term))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.Id,
        text = x.CandidateName
    }); // .ToList() should not be necessary
```