# passing selected value to jQuery's select2 ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm attempting to pass an extra parameter(the selected value) to an ajax call within `multiple select2`:

```
 $("#ddlMultiCourse").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for Course",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
        url: url,//GetCourseList
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                term: params.term, // search term
                value: $("#ddlMultiCourse").val()//extra parameter
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {              

            return {
                results: data

            };
        }

    }
});
```

I actually want to pass another parameter to the ajax call... the previously selected values..

```
 public JsonResult GetCourseList(string term, string[] value)
    {
        try
        {

            var _courseList = _db.MultiCourses
                            .Where(x => x.CourseCode.StartsWith(term))
                            .Select(x => new 
                            {
                                id=x.Id,
                                text=x.CourseCode
                            }).ToList();


            return Json(_courseList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Now I am getting value as null.

Comment: Does `$("#ddlMultiCourse").val()` return an array?. Suggest you first test this by hard codeing a value (say) `value: 'test'` and change the method parameter to `string value`

Comment: I assume then that `$("#ddlMultiCourse").val()` is actually `null`. But that element is the `<select>` your actually applying the `select2`plugin to, which does not makes sense. What are you wanting to pass to the method (and how do you want to use it (currently you don't do anything with parameter `value`)?

Comment: Mate solved the problem by entering the value in a hidden textbox on selecting dropdwnlist, and passing it like above.I needed it because a condition check is there which i was not mentioned above..